# Using C++ and Boost, is it possible to create a std::map of Boost signals?

Tags: c++, boost

Using C++ and Boost, does anybody know if it is possible to create a std::list of pointers to Boost signals?

For example, if I defined the following three separate signals using Boost;

```
boost::signals2::signal<void ()>           signal_A;
boost::signals2::signal<void (int)>        signal_B;
boost::signals2::signal<void (int, int)>   signal_C;
```

how could I then define a std::list into which pointers to all three signals could be inserted? Is there some basic way to do it which I am not thinking of, or do I need to use some clever trick from the Boost libraries?

boost::signals2::signal is not declared as a class is it? Because if it was, and if it inherited from a base class, could I not implement a solution this way?

Any assistance on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you read https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/doc/html/boost/signals2/signal.html? There you can see the base class.

Comment: STL containers are homogeneous, so you need a single type.  You can define an std::variant of those 3 types and store it in the container.

Comment: What would you use it for, anyways? It seems pretty hard to usefully use signals of varying signatures in "bulk". I'll post a "technically correct" answer, but you probably want to rethink your application needs.

Answer (score 0):

I think in general a variant type would be good:

- bounded (std::variant)
- unbounded (std::any)

In this particular case, I'm not convinced it would be very useful. So, you might as well choose a non-owning collection ("view") of the signals like this:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/)**

```
#include <boost/signals2.hpp>
namespace sig = boost::signals2;

int main()
{
    sig::signal<void ()>          signal_A;
    sig::signal<void (int)>       signal_B;
    sig::signal<void (int, int)>  signal_C;

    std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<sig::signal_base>> sigs {
        signal_A,
        signal_B,
        signal_C 
    };

    for (sig::signal_base& s : sigs) {

    }
}
```